# Roassal: Conditional X Axis Labeling

Tags: smalltalk, roassal

In my chart, the x axis represents the Date. I'd like to only label the first day of a month.
Specifying a number of ticks is problematic because they can be fractional.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
someRoassalObject
  if: [ :point | point date dayOfMonth = 1 ]
  label: [ :point | point date mmddyyyy ]
```

(where points are my domain objects that respond to `#date`)

I did the following quick and dirty hack in the mean time:

```
b axisConfiguration
        labelConvertion: [ :x | (Date julianDayNumber: x rounded) mmddyyyy ].
```